# Ubuntu 16.04 - sudo pm-hibernate not working

Tags: 16.04, hibernate

When I do `sudo pm-hibernate` , the screen just turns off for a second and then comes back up.
I checked the log using `head /var/log/pm-suspend.log` , and here is the result:

```
Initial commandline parameters: 
Wed Dec 21 12:11:34 IST 2016: Running hooks for hibernate.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change hibernate hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change hibernate hibernate: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status hibernate hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status hibernate hibernate: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging hibernate hibernate:
Linux woem-HP-ProBook-4540s 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

GParted shows that I have 7.2 GB linux-swap, which is almost twice my RAM.

How do I proceed now?

EDIT :
I opened pm-suspend.log and scrolled to the bottom of the file. Here is the result:

```
Wed Dec 21 14:04:16 IST 2016: performing hibernate

sh: echo: I/O error

Wed Dec 21 14:04:25 IST 2016: Awake.

Wed Dec 21 14:04:25 IST 2016: Running hooks for thaw

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend thaw hibernate:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend thaw hibernate: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video thaw hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video thaw hibernate: success.


Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler thaw hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler thaw hibernate: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led thaw hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led thaw hibernate: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm thaw hibernate:

/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0x80 (128)
 APM_level  = 128

/dev/sda:
setting standby to 36 (3 minutes)
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm thaw hibernate: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron thaw hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron thaw hibernate: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq thaw hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq thaw hibernate: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock thaw hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock thaw hibernate: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules thaw hibernate:
Reloaded unloaded modules.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules thaw hibernate: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant thaw hibernate:
Selected interface 'wlo1'
OK
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant thaw hibernate: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx thaw hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx thaw hibernate: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/49tlp thaw hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/49tlp thaw hibernate: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/40inputattach thaw hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/40inputattach thaw hibernate: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate thaw hibernate:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate thaw hibernate: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common thaw hibernate:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common thaw hibernate: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave thaw hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave thaw hibernate: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging thaw hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging thaw hibernate: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status thaw hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status thaw hibernate: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change thaw hibernate:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change thaw hibernate: success.

Wed Dec 21 14:04:30 IST 2016: Finished.
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to install some few packages, run the following commands:

`sudo apt install molly-guard`

`sudo apt install pm-utils`

Then restart the terminal, and run the following:

`sudo pm-hibernate`

That's all :)

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then try `sudo pm-hibernate` This will take atleast 1-2 min for hibernate